# Laravel - A link to [http link 2] with target blank go to http://localhost:8000[http link 2] instead of [http link 2]

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel 5.2.
I've two links to external pages:

```
<div class="logos">
    <a href="{{URL::to('[http link 1]') }}" target="_blank"><img src="{{URL::asset('img/logos/name1.png')}}" alt="" /></a>
    <a href="​​​{{URL::to('[http link 2]') }}" target="_blank"><img src="{{URL::asset('img/logos/name2.png')}}" alt="" /></a>
  </div>
```

[Http link 1] work properly, but link 2 direct to http://localhost:8000[http link 2] instead og [http link 2]

I've used [http link 1/2] because SO not allow my actual real link (They are bit.ly/something)

What's wrong with second link, it's coded equal to link 1,
but it behaves in a different manner.

Comment: What browser did you use? Did you try with another browser? What is the output HTML?

Comment: check by inspect element what url made for link 2

Comment: Just in case, try clearing your cached views by running `php artisan view:clear`

Comment: Chrome 51, No, I tried only in chrome. Output HTML is a regular/valid html (first link worked properly, second no). I've checked with chrome inspector and link 2 is  http://localhost:8000http://[link2] instead link 1 is http://[link1]

Comment: Running php artisan view:clear nothing change, behaviour remain the same